# Recreating Minecraft-like Voxel Lighting in Eevee or Cycles

Tags: light, texture-baking, lighting, shadows

I've ported the model of a world from the game Minecraft into Blender to transfer to another game engine altogether, however I can't seem to properly recreate the in-game lighting for baking.

From what I understand of how the lighting in Minecraft works, (from here: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Light) every block that releases light does so in a pattern like so:

[image: Light coming off of blocks in-game]

Light falls off discretely for 16 levels between fully lit and fully dark, and the light patterns can overlap with other blocks that release or absorb light as well as the ambient light from the sky, resulting in this (the torches are the main blocks emitting light in this particular shot):

[image: Lighting before interpolation]

before applying interpolation between blocks (and ambient occlusion in model corners) to make the lighting look smoother in the final result:

[image: Lighting after interpolation]

While I understand some of how it works on the surface, I can't grasp how to implement such lighting in EEVEE or Cycles.

I do know however that once I do get such a setup running I could bake it into a texture with closest pixel interpolation, with each face of every "block" of the world taking up one pixel of the image to preserve the effect, applying interpolation as needed to finish the effect off in-engine.

Other than shading the model by hand (which would be extremely tedious) I don't see how to recreate this properly enough to resemble the source material well, so help would be much appreciated. If such a lighting scheme is impossible to recreate, then one with a similarly-functioning aesthetic might satisfy my needs.

Comment: Did you think of just baking the lighting in that "other game engine"? It could be faster and just easier. Im also not sure how well it would export if you got the lighting to bake like that. Maybe baked lighting would transfer smoothly to the other game engine but it could potentially not. However if you baked it into a texture it could look weird.

Comment: in the game engine you could make it so based on the distance the object is to the the light within a certain area (cube) it could effect the overall "whiteness" of the objects texture/material.

Comment: The game engine that I'm porting to requires all environment lighting to be baked on level geometry. Normally this would be done by baking to vertex colors, but due to how Minecraft's lighting works that becomes problematic to do practically. So assuming I can recreate the lighting solution in blender I can bake to either vertex colors or a texture.

Comment: That is unfortunate... What game engine are you using?